# Search API Facebook Graph by date range

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

is there any way to explore the Facebook Graph API by date range? Ex. to find all events on February?
I use following code, but I’m not sure, that’s correct request:

```
since=2015-01-28T00:00:00%2B0000&until=2015-01-30T00:00:00%2B00000
```

In this way, I get records for defined date range - ok, but there is missing events – a set is incomplete (despite it doesn’t exceed a limit of API). Why I can’t get all of results for given query?

Maybe do you know another method of filtering results by date?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to restrict the search results by `since` and `until` as far as I know.

For searching events, you can use the `/search` endpoint as described at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search

but I guess there's no further way to filter the results other than specifying the `q` parameter.

Comment: In Graph Explorer (that use newest vesion of API) there is anothet error - "Must be a unixtime or a date/time representation parseable by strtotime()", so maybe it supports date range filtering when I change it for unix format? I'm going test it.